What criteria does Google use for deciding to traverse a road with StreetView?
Until recently I had always assumed that (in Europe, at least - I have no experience elsewhere) StreetView only covered hard-surfaced roads (ashphalt, concrete...). But recently I came across this coastal dirt track in Spain. Considering it had been ridden by Google's vehicle, I decided it would be OK to ride it on a road bike (I didn't have an MTB).
For future cycling decisions like this, it would be good to know how Google decides.

Google also does underwater Google Streetview partnered with the Catlin Seaview Survey, https://www.google.com/maps/about/behind-the-scenes/streetview/treks/oceans/ you can apply to help create street view with an Insta360 Pro 2 Camera https://www.google.com/streetview/contribute/

You can check this "How it works".
It seems Street View also captures images in narrow streets or places that can only be reach on foot.

Thank you for the link - this describes mainly how it works (as per title) but not why they choose some streets/tracks but not others
